# How to make websocket async/multithreaded?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I wanted this code:

```
import websocket
import json


STREAM_HOST = 'wss://realtime.aax.com/marketdata/v2/'


def on_open(ws):
    ws.send(json.dumps({"e": "subscribe", "stream": ["BTCUSDT@book_50", "BTCUSDT@trade", "tickers"]}))


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection closed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(STREAM_HOST,
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.run_forever(ping_interval=1)
```

rewrite by using async or any multithread module.
I tried this, but when I run the code, it shows nothing and finish instantly:

```
import json
import websockets
import asyncio


STREAM_HOST = 'wss://realtime.aax.com/marketdata/v2/'
SUBSCRIBE = {"e": "subscribe", "stream": ["BTCUSDT@book_50", "BTCUSDT@trade", "tickers"]}


async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(STREAM_HOST) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(SUBSCRIBE))
        await websocket.recv()


asyncio.run(hello())
```

What I missed? How to write this websocket sample in a async/multithreaded way so It will show the real time data?
How to do it?

Comment: you never print anything, what do you mean? Consider using a translator if its hard to explain.

Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71384132/best-approach-to-multiple-websocket-client-connections-in-python

Comment: when I run the code, it shows nothing (*fixed)

Comment: yes, this is because you never print anything, so no wonder it doesnt show you anything in the terminal, you could do `print(await websocket.recv())` in the last line of your hello function, for example, does your code finish instantly, is that what you meant to say?

Comment: Yes, my code is finish instantly for some reason. And with your print the responce is - {"e":"system","status":[{"all":"active"}]}, not the real time market data

Comment: well sadly i dont know what your client does, sooo i cant really fix that. Please take a look at the first comment and the link i provided

Comment: In your first version you ```run_forever``` the equivalent is missing in your asyncio version so I suspect there are co-routines idle when you exit your code.